# Turning a numeric range into a sequential range

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data set of about 9000 with Territory ranges of the form [1-5,10-99,100-115] I want to expand the data and the rows to be of the form in the provided data set.

My first thought was possibly looping through the Series 'Terri' and running it through pd.series(range(i,100)) but that wouldnt create the below output.

Appreciate the assistance.

```
import pandas as pd
d={'Peril':['Fire','Wind'],'Terri':[1-5,6-10],'Premium':[100,200]}
output={'Peril':['Fire','Fire','Fire','Fire','Fire','Wind','Wind','Wind','Wind','Wind'],'Terri':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],'Premium':[100,100,100,100,100,200,200,200,200,200]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
expected_output=pd.DataFrame(data=output)
```

Comment: `[1-5,6-10]` is just the same as `[-4,-4]`. Is this the real representation of your data or would you mean `['1-5','6-10']`?

Comment: Can you clarify your expected input and output in a better way

Comment: Apologies, ['1-5','6-10'] is the correct interpretation

Answer (score 4):

Use a couple of helper list comprehensions, then use [`pandas.index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html), [`DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and [`numpy.hstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

ranges = [np.arange(s, e+1) for s, e in [list(map(int, x)) for x in df.Terri.str.split('-')]]
lens = [len(x) for x in ranges]

df_new = df.loc[df.index.repeat(lens)].assign(Terri=np.hstack(ranges))
```

[out]

```
  Peril  Terri  Premium
0  Fire      1      100
0  Fire      2      100
0  Fire      3      100
0  Fire      4      100
0  Fire      5      100
1  Wind      6      200
1  Wind      7      200
1  Wind      8      200
1  Wind      9      200
1  Wind     10      200
```

For reference, `ranges` looks like:

```
[array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), array([ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10])]
```

`lens` looks like:

```
[5, 5]
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `Terri` is meant to contain string ranges, instead of subtraction operations, you can create a DataFrame of your ranges and then `stack` to benefit from `join`ing on a common index to expand the original frame.

---

```
u = df['Terri'].str.split('-', expand=True).astype(int).values

j = pd.DataFrame(
    [np.arange(start, stop+1) for start, stop in u]
)

j.stack().reset_index(1, drop=True).to_frame('Terri')

df.drop('Terri', 1).join(f)
```

```
  Peril  Premium  Terri
0  Fire      100      1
0  Fire      100      2
0  Fire      100      3
0  Fire      100      4
0  Fire      100      5
1  Wind      200      6
1  Wind      200      7
1  Wind      200      8
1  Wind      200      9
1  Wind      200     10
```

---

Since the behavior of `stack` will drop null values, your ranges don't have to be a uniform length.

Answer (score 2):

The only way this works is if you're starting DataFrame's `Terri` column is a string:

```
d={'Peril':['Fire','Wind'],'Terri':['1-5','6-10'],'Premium':[100,200]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)
#  Peril Terri  Premium
#0  Fire   1-5      100
#1  Wind  6-10      200
```

If you split the string in the `Terri` column on the `-`, you can use it as an input to `range`, except you'd need to add one to the stop value to include the endpoint. To make that easier, you can define your own range function:

```
def myRange(a, b):
    return range(a, b+1)
```

Now you can split the column, apply the `myRange` function, and stack the result:

```
temp = pd.DataFrame(
    df['Terri'].str.split("-")\
        .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(myRange(*map(int, x))))\
        .stack()\
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True),
    columns=["Terri"]
)
print(temp)
#   Terri
#0      1
#0      2
#0      3
#0      4
#0      5
#1      6
#1      7
#1      8
#1      9
#1     10
```

Finally join this result back with your original DataFrame:

```
print(df.drop(["Terri"], axis=1).join(temp))
#  Peril  Premium  Terri
#0  Fire      100      1
#0  Fire      100      2
#0  Fire      100      3
#0  Fire      100      4
#0  Fire      100      5
#1  Wind      200      6
#1  Wind      200      7
#1  Wind      200      8
#1  Wind      200      9
#1  Wind      200     10
```

The same thing, condensed:

```
df.drop(["Terri"], axis=1).join(
    pd.DataFrame(
        df['Terri'].str.split("-")\
            .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(myRange(*map(int, x))))\
            .stack()\
            .reset_index(level=1, drop=True),
        columns=["Terri"]
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If `[1-5,6-10]` actually is `['1-5','6-10']`, then the code bellow may work:

```
new_df = []
for row in df.iterrows():
    rng = row[1]['Terri']
    rng = rng.split('-')
    start, end = int(rng[0]), int(rng[1])
    for n in range(start, end+1):
        new_row = {
            'Peril': row[1]['Peril'],
            'Terri': n,
            'Premium': row[1]['Premium'],
        }
        new_df.append(new_row)
output = pd.DataFrame(new_df)
```